# Can drive hardware failure cause kernel panic

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid

I have an old linux box with a 6 disk RAID in it. Recently one of the drives failed so I replaced it and rebuilt the RAID. Worked for a little while but now the machine kernel panics constantly. I swapped out the RAM, same thing. I do see ata hard errors on the console shortly after booting. I suspect more of the original RAID drives have gone bad.

Unfortunately the machine is so unstable now I can barely get it to stay up for more than a few minutes before it panics.

Any advice/ideas?

Comment: Rule out the drives one by one, starting with the newest drive added. Take a drive out, wait for a panic, if it does panic still then replace drive and try the next. Repeat until it no longer panics. If it always panics then something else has failed, either the software configuration is corrupt or some other hardware has failed. If you can access the raid array from a Linux live DVD then chances are it is a software problem.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is a drive test. There are a variety of bootable disk utilities that test the health of Hard Drives.  Often times there will even be built in diagnostics available in the BIOS settings.

One simple but effective tool I like to use is [Drive Fitness Test](https://www.hgst.com/hdd/support/download.htm#DFT). This will tool will essentially go through the drive looking for bad sectors as well as performing a number of other basic checks in the process.

If DFT, or other disk checking tools report that the drive is failing (diagnostics in red box) you should look at imaging the bad drive immediately.